# Has GRRM ever confirmed that he named some ASOIAF characters after the Muppets?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, inspiration

In The World of Ice and Fire, we are introduced to few historical Tully characters, which are:

1. Lord [Kermit Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kermit_Tully)
2. Lord [Elmo Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Elmo_Tully)
3. Lord [Grover Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grover_Tully)

To those who may not be familiar with [the Muppets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Muppets), these three Lords share the same names as Puppet Characters from the cast of popular shows like [Sesame Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_Street), which are:

1. [Kermit the Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_the_Frog)
2. [Elmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmo)
3. [Grover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover)

The coincidence doesn't end there. Tully family ruled Riverlands. Riverlands has three Forks contributing to River Trident:

1. [Green Fork](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Green_Fork)
2. [Red Fork](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Fork)
3. [Blue Fork](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Blue_Fork)

Guess what colors Kermit, Elmo and Grover are ?

[image: Kermit][image: Elmo][image: Grover]

This is definitely not just a coincidence.

ASOIAF wiki [confirms](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Kermit_Tully#Behind_the_Scenes):

> Kermit, his father Elmo, and his great-grandfather Grover are
>   references by George R. R. Martin to The Muppets.

But there is no reference added as to where exactly did GRRM confirm that was the case. Googling doesn't yield any statement from GRRM or his team. Has GRRM ever confirmed that he was indeed influenced by the beloved puppet characters while naming the Tully Lords?

Comment: I would say it is quite possible as Wun-Wun, is named after Phil Simms, an American Football player for the New York *Giants*. His jersey number was 11 = one one = wun wun.

Comment: @Skooba Indeed there are many such references to be found in ASOIAF. I read somewhere that Wun Wun is actually a mockery of the nickname Won Won JKR created for Ron (As used by Lavender)

Comment: But of course [you are correct](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/FAQ/Entry/Are_there_any_nods_to_other_works_in_the_series), he is named after Phil Simms

Comment: Some one really needs to make the SSM on the Citadel searchable....

Comment: @Skooba It is [searchable](http://www.westeros.org/Search/1250e8585d8cb67349fe117f74238350/). There is a searchbar on the bottom. Searching "Muppets" however returns no results so I assume GRRM never confirmed it.

Comment: Does it ***need*** confirmation?

Comment: @Randal'Thor [Yessss](https://media.giphy.com/media/1qweexqh24KuA/giphy.gif). I mean yeah it is obvious but the fact that the claim is unreferenced on wiki is bothering me. I want to add it there as well

Comment: Mind blown. . . .

Comment: One other thing to note.
So, yes there is a muppet connection (or dare I say, a Rainbow Connection) with the Tully’s. Elmo, Grover, Kermit, and even Oscar. However, there’s one more that I think was missed. Lysa apparently tried to keep it going with her son...”Robin”, which also happens to be the name of Kermit the Frog’s nephew.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Yes, George R. R. Martin did intentionally name the three Tully Lords after the Muppets.**

As confirmed by [Elio Garcia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/59933/elio-miguel-garcia-jr) via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/westerosorg/status/849162581721874432):

> Yep. Not sure why exactly, other than it amused him, but the colors of the three muppets has been noted (Red, Green, Blue)
> ...
> There was also an Oscar, brother to Kermit, but he didn't make it into TWoIaF.
> <sup>Elio Garcia, Twitter, [2017-04-04](https://twitter.com/westerosorg/status/849162581721874432)</sup>

[image: Image capture from a Twitter conversation between user 'IamMooz' and 'Westerosorg' (Twitter account representing Elio Garcia). 'Mooz' asks "Is there confirmation that The George named the three Tullys after the Muppets? (Elmo, Kermit & Grover Tully)." and Elio replies "Yep. Not sure why exactly, other than it amused him, but the colors of the three muppets has been noted (Red, Green, Blue)... There was also an Oscar, brother to Kermit, but he didn't make it into TWoIaF.]

Why should you believe this answer?

1. I'm awesome
2. [Elio Garcia and Linda Antonsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elio_Garcia_and_Linda_Antonsson) are George R. R. Martin's collaborators, and in many cases, second-in-command.
3. Elio and Linda co-wrote *The World of Ice and Fire* as well as being the creators and moderators of westeros.org.